Is Rishabdev who is worshipped by Jains the same as the one mentioned in Shrimad Bhagvat or he is Shiva?
In Bhagavat Puran Rishabhadev is mentioned as Avatar of Vishnu Bhagwan. In Shiv Puran also an Avatar of Shiv Bhagwan is mentioned as Vrishabh.

Yes, however the Jain philosophy is said to be a misunderstanding of the actual teachings of Rishabhadeva (started by a king named Arhat). This is described in the Bhagavata Purana. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/6/

It's the same Rishabha as Jainism. Just like in Jain texts, he is the son of Nabhi and the father of Bharata. Just like in the Jain texts, India got the name Bharata from Rishabha's son Bharata.

The region of Himahvaya was ruled by the great Nabhi. With his queen,
Merudevī, he had a brilliant son, Rsabha. Rsabha himself had a hundred
sons, of whom Bharata was the eldest. Having ruled wisely and
performed varied  sacrifices, King Rsabha placed his son heroic
Bharata upon the throne, then that fortunate man retired to the ashram
of Pulaha to undertake austerities. Following the prescription for
those who retire to the forest, that resolute king duly performed
austerities and instituted sacrifices.Wasted by his practices, he grew
thin, his veins distended. Naked Rsabha placed a pebble in his mouth
and took the path of heroes. Because this region was given to Bharata
by his father when he retired to the forest, it’s known throughout the
threefold worlds as Bhārata.


Chapter 4, 5th Skandha, Srimad Bhagavatam.


In the Shrimad Bhagavatam, Rishabdev is described in Canto 5, Chapters 4-6, where he is portrayed as an incarnation of Lord Vishnu who teaches detachment and spiritual values. In Jain texts, such as the Kalpa Sutra, Rishabdev is acknowledged as the first Tirthankara, emphasizing his role in establishing Jain teachings. The references highlight both his spiritual significance and the differences in interpretation across these traditions.
